# Aggregating data using python

Tags: python, pandas, count, sum, aggregate

I have some data that I want to both sum and count based upon a certain field. My data looks like this

```
Value  ID    Object
100    ABD   Type1
200    ABD   Type1
400    ABD   Type2
200    BCE   Type1
100    BCE   Type1
800    JHO   Type3
600    TVM   Type4
```

And I am trying to get to this where I have counted the number of **unique** Objects related to an ID and also summed the total value also related to that ID

```
ValueSum  ID    CountObject
700       ABD   2  
300       BCE   1
800       JHO   1 
600       TVM   1
```

What I have been taking a look at is using the `.groupby.()` function along with `.count()` and `.sum()` but I can't seem to get things in the right format.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: what is your input, text file, dataframe, raw string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a dict of the funcs to perform on multiple columns on your df using [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once):

```
In [289]:
gp = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'Value':sum, 'Object':'nunique'})
gp = gp.rename(columns={'Value':'ValueSum', 'Object':'ObjectCount'})
gp

Out[289]:
    ID  ValueSum  ObjectCount
0  ABD       700            2
1  BCE       300            1
2  JHO       800            1
3  TVM       600            1
```

Here we pass a dict with the corresponding column names and the func to perform, for the counting we use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) which returns the number of unique values

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. The only thing is it doesn't count the number of unique records, it counts the total number.